# Which article should be used in the following sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Which article should I use before the word “email”?

> We’ve sent (**an/the**) email to address@gmail.com
>
> (**An/The**) email has been sent to address@gmail.com

I’ve noticed the website Bitbucket responded `We’ve sent an email` after I signed up. But I can’t understand why the article “an” is used there, if the site knows what mail it is talking about.

Answer (score 8):

Either article could be considered correct, depending on the circumstances and the assumptions involved.

On one hand, we can use the indefinite article, because we are merely talking about some email that has been sent. As Michael Rybkin mentioned in an earlier answer, sentences like these are perfectly grammatical and frequently heard in everyday speech:

- I took **an** apple out of the fruit bowl.
- I bought **a** washing machine last week.
- I sent **a** package to my uncle.
- I sent **an** email to Mike two hours ago.

However, you're onto something when you mentioned that the site knows which email is being referred to. There are many possible situations where using the definite article would also be acceptable. One very simple one, often quoted in elementary grammar books, is that the item being alluded to has been previously mentioned.

> Here is ***an*** apple. I took ***the*** apple out of the fruit bowl.

But this "previous mention" need not always be so obvious, explicit or immediate.  For example, consider these snippets of dialogue between spouses:

> **Q**: Hey, why is there only $200 left in our checking account?
>   **A**: Remember? I bought ***the*** washing machine last week.
>
> **Q**: I didn't hear you leave. Where did you go?
>   **A**: To the post office; I sent ***the*** package to my uncle.

The first answer sounds fine, because we assume there is only one washing machine in the house. The second answer would be fine, too, if we can assume the couple may have had a dialogue a few days ago that went something like this:

> **Q**: What's up with this big box on the counter?
>   **A**: It's a package for my uncle Ernie. His birthday is next week.

As for that last one, we can use the definite article there, too:

> **Q**: Did you send that "save the date" notice to your cousin yet?
>   **A**: Yes, I sent ***the*** email to Mike two hours ago.

I could say "an email" just as easily as I can say "the email". In either case we know we are talking about an email that contains the "save the date" information.

As for your message, I think this sounds perfectly fine:

> We’ve sent ***an*** email to address@gmail.com

However, the company could have also written:

> We’ve sent ***the*** email to address@gmail.com

and I'd interpret that as:

> We’ve sent the email [*that we previously indicated would be sent*] to address@gmail.com

However, we are not forced to use the definite article just because a forthcoming email may have been previously mentioned.

---

As a footnote, notice how no mention was ever made of the fruit bowl, but the word "the" sounds perfectly natural in that sentence.

Comment: Related to your footnote and the discussion about "the washing machine," I think the key element is that the listener can easily discern which specific object is under discussion. The couple can easily discern that the washing machine referenced is the one they own, since it was bought with their money and they presumably both know one was purchased recently. The fruit bowl is more interesting, since there might be more than one bowl of fruit in a home or building, but the context might make it clear there's a particular one nearby or a particular one the speaker usually gets fruit from.

Comment: To summarise, use _the_ when only one thing is likely.

Answer (score 5):

You use the article "**the**" when you're talking about something that is known already (for example you talked about it before) or for something specific or particular that you're supposed to know about it, and you use the article "a" or "an" when you're talking about that is unknown or for something non-specific or non particular, that you're not supposed to know about it.

Now talking about your specific case:

**If you have not been told before** that an email is going to be sent to you, then the usage of the indefinite article "**an**" is the correct choice.

But

**if you have been told before** that an email will be sent to you, then in the second time they already should say

> "**The** email has been sent to address "gmail.com".

It does not matter that the site knows abour its email because it should talk also according to your knowledge (compare monolog wilith dialogue), and if you have not been told before about an email, they shouldn't use the definite article "the".

In the end of the day, typical sites are not always the best place to learn English Grammar.

Comment: So, *An email has been sent to the address gmail.com.* is not correct?

Comment: In my humble opinion, as I explained, both can be correct and incorrect. It depends on the context. I explained it in details when the article "a" is the correct one and when the article "the" is the correct one. Take a look in my answer and if something isn't clear I'll do my best to explain it.

Comment: Well, from what I can read in the OP's question, they didn't say *the email*. They said *an email*. And the OP is asking why *an* was used instead of *the*.

Comment: That's 100% right but it is compatible with my explanation for his question. I added more elucidation to my answer now to address directly the OP's question.

Comment: +1 for "typical sites are not always the best place to learn".  Plenty of websites will "forget" they already mentioned the email, and call it "an email" later.

Comment: @DarrenR - I don't think it's necessarily a grammatical gaffe to use "an" instead of "the" in that case – particularly if the email happens to be the first of many (which unfortunately seems to be the case all too often nowadays).

Answer (score 3):

Either one can be used depending on the context. If you're wondering why they have specifically chosen to use *an* instead of *the*, then here's the reasoning. What exactly has been sent to you? Well, an email has been sent to you as opposed to something else. So, they didn't send you a computer. They didn't send you a washing machine. They sent you an email! This is like a notification message telling you that something has been sent to you and that something is an email.

This would be similar to a situation where you go out and buy a car and then later that day you say to one of your friends that you bought a car today. There are millions of things in the world that you can buy. But you bought a car as opposed to a washing machine or a house. And there are millions of cars in the world too. You just happen to have bought one of them. That's why in this context you would be referring to the car that you bought as *a car* and as *the car*.

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't understand your answer. To your opinion using of **indefinite article** is for ejection nouns that are not told? If I say an email why should I think that it is a computer rather than email? I think as the professional books say and as they their term-names say: "Definite" and "indefinite article" that in the end of the day means that the articles are for specific / particular or for non specific / non particular noun. Let me know even one serious reference that supports your opinion.

Comment: **The process of signing up has been successfully completed. An email containing further instructions has been sent to the address someone@somewhere.com.** -- does this example sound fine to you? We're using *an* because we're talking about any old email. Do you understand what I'm saying?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case (a company tells you they sent you an/the email):

**If the email has previously been referred to:**
`the`

> We will sent you an email with information about logging in. The email has been sent.

**If the email has not been referred to:**
`an`

> We sent an email about logging in.

Comment: The "already referred to" litmus test is a very general one, and it doesn't really cover all the reasons one might choose `the` instead of `a` or `an`. _The Louvre is a museum in the city of Paris_. That sentence uses the definite article two times; it is grammatical and understandable, but neither one of us had mentioned the Louvre or Paris yet.

Comment: @J.R.Yes, but I answered only to his specific case. Louvre is a name, email isn't. If you want me to, I can add all reasons why one would use either one of the articles, but I only wanted to answer for the word email used in that context.

Comment: I find this answer misleading, but that's just me.

Comment: @LucianSava - It's not just you...

Comment: @J.R. Could you please give me a situation in this specific case where my rule is incorrect?

Comment: In this specific case, what you've said may be true. However, because your answer only applies to this specific case, I don't think it's very useful for the learner. Assume I said: "The lion is the king of the jungle." A learner might read your answer and conclude that I must have spoken incorrectly, because no lion, king, or jungle has previously been referred to. And next thing you know, we'll have someone asking another ELL question about why the Tokens are singing _Near the village, the peaceful village, the lion sleeps tonight_. I mean, why should an email be different than any of those?

Answer (score 1):

From the company's point of view, they send many emails and only one is going to you.

> We’ve sent **an** email to address@gmail.com.
>
> We’ve sent **one of our many** emails to address@gmail.com.

When context makes it likely that only one thing is meant, you can use *the*.

> **The** house was cold last night!

Which house? The speaker's house, or the house that they spent the night in.

> I tripped and hit my head on **the** ground.

The entire solid part of the earth's surface is called **the** ground.

> **The** earth is the planet where we live.

There is only one Earth, but many planets. I've said which planet which is why ***the** planet* is correct, although a different effect is given by using ***a** planet*:

> The earth is **a** planet where we live.

Our planet is not so special because there are lots of planets.

> I just got **the** email!

I was expecting it; it's a noteworthy email.

> I just got **an** email!

I probably wasn't expecting it, or I was expecting several emails and one arrived.

Back to the company. If they told you they were going to send you an email beforehand, they could then say:

> We’ve sent **the** email to address@gmail.com.
>
> We’ve sent **the email we previously told you about** to address@gmail.com.

So, *the* is used when:

- there is only one of that object in everyday use

  - > **the ground**
  - > **the sky**
- there is only one associated with the speaker (the house, the head, the train)

  - > I got hit on **the head**
  - > **The train** was late today
- the object has been previously mentioned

  - > I will send you an email. **The** email will tell you how to log in to your account.

Note: it can change from one to another in the natural course:

> **The** house was cold last night! (speaker association)
>   Why was **the** house cold? (previously mentioned)